# How to inject variables to git submodule foreach?

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

I have 2 questions, (1) How to inject a variable into this `foreach` loop? in below example, `$user_branch` is not accessible in line 2.

```
USER_BRANCH="foo"
git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'branch="$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch)"; [ "$branch" = "" ] && git checkout $USER_BRANCH || git checkout $branch' –
```

(2) Is there a way to make this `foreach` into a regular loop?, something like:

```
foreach $(git submodules --recursive); do
  #do something
  #more
  #and more
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing your first question, the problem is that you are using single quotes so your variable doesn't get expanded. Switching to double quotes should fix that part.

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive "git checkout $user_branch"
```

For the second question, the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) suggests that you can run arbitrary shell commands in each module, so while you can't structure it like a bash for loop, you can run either a shell script or multiple commands concatenated by `;`.

> foreach [--recursive]
>
> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule. The command has access to the variables $name, $path, $sha1
>   and $toplevel: $name is the name of the relevant submodule section in
>   .gitmodules, $path is the name of the submodule directory relative to
>   the superproject, $sha1 is the commit as recorded in the superproject,
>   and $toplevel is the absolute path to the top-level of the
>   superproject. Any submodules defined in the superproject but not
>   checked out are ignored by this command. Unless given --quiet, foreach
>   prints the name of each submodule before evaluating the command. If
>   --recursive is given, submodules are traversed recursively (i.e. the given shell command is evaluated in nested submodules as well). A
>   non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the
>   processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding || : to the
>   end of the command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have to do something like `git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'branch="$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch)"; [ "$branch" = "" ] && git checkout $USER_BRANCH || git checkout $branch' –`, not sure how to replace single quote with double " in this, any help ?

Comment: `git submodule foreach -q --recursive "branch=\"$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch)\"; [ -z \"$branch\" ] && git checkout $USER_BRANCH || git checkout $branch"` — escape dquotes inside dquotes with backslashes.

Comment: @rodee, If you're doing something moderately complex, I'd wrap it in a shell script.